# Iphone tableview horizontal scrollbar appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have tableview that scroll vertically. My question is when first this view is loaded, horizontal scrollbar appears at the bottom of tableview and disappears. It only happens when the view loads at the first time. I wonder why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd hazard a guess that you accidentally checked the “Horizontal Scrollers” box in the table's properties in Interface Builder. To turn them back off again, either find that (under the “Scroll View” section of the inspector) and uncheck it, or just set the table view's `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` property to `NO` in your controller's `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't modify anything under scroll View section, it's ridiculous but by default both horizontal and vertical box was checked when I created table view.